# What notion of ordering is the important for identifying bottlenecks in Theory of Constraints?

Tags: constraint

In many systems the completion of an activity takes an amount of time that is not perfectly predictable. In statistics we would consider these to be [random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable).

For two measurements of time $t_1$ and $t_2$ I can readily evaluate $\mathbb{1} [t_1 \leq t_2]$. When I consider the ensemble of measurement outcomes I have to consider $\mathbb{1} [T_1 \leq T_2]$ which compares random variables.

Considering ordering on random quantities like this is termed [stochastic ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_ordering), with particular notions of [stochastic dominance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance) coming to mind.

In [ToC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_constraints) we would like to identity which activities in a sequence is the slowest step, termed a "bottleneck". But knowing that different notions of stochastic ordering raises a question of what form of stochastic dominance is the most relevant in order to make ToC work?